# I want to draw my bubble chart to a div element. How am i supposed to append it to a div element for the following code

Tags: jquery, d3.js

//html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello Bubble Chart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,600,200italic,600italic&subset=latin,vietnamese' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/d3-transform/src/d3-transform.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/cafej/src/extarray.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/cafej/src/misc.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/cafej/src/micro-observer.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/microplugin/src/microplugin.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/bubble-chart/src/bubble-chart.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/bubble-chart/src/plugins/central-click/central-click.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/bubble-chart/src/plugins/lines/lines.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <style>
    .bubbleChart {
      min-width: 100px;
      max-width: 700px;
      height: 700px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .bubbleChart svg{
      background: #000000;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="background: #000000">
<div class="bubbleChart"/>
</body>
</html>
```

//Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var bubbleChart = new d3.svg.BubbleChart({
    supportResponsive: true,
    //container: => use @default
    size: 600,
    //viewBoxSize: => use @default
    innerRadius: 600 / 3.5,
    //outerRadius: => use @default
    radiusMin: 50,
    //radiusMax: use @default
    //intersectDelta: use @default
    //intersectInc: use @default
    //circleColor: use @default
    data: {
      items: [
        {text: "Java", count: "236"},
        {text: ".Net", count: "382"},
        {text: "Php", count: "170"},
        {text: "Ruby", count: "123"},
        {text: "D", count: "12"},
        {text: "Python", count: "170"},
        {text: "C/C++", count: "382"},
        {text: "Pascal", count: "10"},
        {text: "Something", count: "170"},
      ],
      eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
      classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
    },
    plugins: [
      {
        name: "central-click",
        options: {
          text: "(See more detail)",
          style: {
            "font-size": "12px",
            "font-style": "italic",
            "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
            //"font-weight": "700",
            "text-anchor": "middle",
            "fill": "white"
          },
          attr: {dy: "65px"},
          centralClick: function() {
            alert("Here is more details!!");
          }
        }
      },
      {
        name: "lines",
        options: {
          format: [
            {// Line #0
              textField: "count",
              classed: {count: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "28px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "0px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            },
            {// Line #1
              textField: "text",
              classed: {text: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "14px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "20px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            }
          ],
          centralFormat: [
            {// Line #0
              style: {"font-size": "50px"},
              attr: {}
            },
            {// Line #1
              style: {"font-size": "30px"},
              attr: {dy: "40px"}
            }
          ]
        }
      }]
  });
});
```

//Here i want my code to be appended to an external div element and I also want to remove alert for central bubble. I couldn't find that. Please suggest me how to proceed :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the bubble chart component that you are using can be found at https://github.com/phuonghuynh/bubble-chart/blob/master/api/bubble-chart.md

This is linked to from http://phuonghuynh.github.io/ which is probably a good read, if you want to use the components discussed there.

Anyway, try the below snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var bubbleChart = new d3.svg.BubbleChart({
    supportResponsive: true,
    //container: => use @default
    size: 600,
    //viewBoxSize: => use @default
    innerRadius: 600 / 3.5,
    //outerRadius: => use @default
    radiusMin: 50,
    //radiusMax: use @default
    //intersectDelta: use @default
    //intersectInc: use @default
    //circleColor: use @default
    container: "#newBubbleChart",
    data: {
      items: [
        {text: "Java", count: "236"},
        {text: ".Net", count: "382"},
        {text: "Php", count: "170"},
        {text: "Ruby", count: "123"},
        {text: "D", count: "12"},
        {text: "Python", count: "170"},
        {text: "C/C++", count: "382"},
        {text: "Pascal", count: "10"},
        {text: "Something", count: "170"},
      ],
      eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
      classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
    },
    plugins: [
/*
      {
        name: "central-click",
        options: {
          text: "(See more detail)",
          style: {
            "font-size": "12px",
            "font-style": "italic",
            "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
            //"font-weight": "700",
            "text-anchor": "middle",
            "fill": "white"
          },
          attr: {dy: "65px"},
          centralClick: function() {
            alert("Here is more details!!");
          }
        }
      },
*/
      {
        name: "lines",
        options: {
          format: [
            {// Line #0
              textField: "count",
              classed: {count: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "28px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "0px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            },
            {// Line #1
              textField: "text",
              classed: {text: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "14px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "20px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            }
          ],
          centralFormat: [
            {// Line #0
              style: {"font-size": "50px"},
              attr: {}
            },
            {// Line #1
              style: {"font-size": "30px"},
              attr: {dy: "40px"}
            }
          ]
        }
      }]
  });
});
```

```css
    .bubbleChart {
      min-width: 100px;
      max-width: 700px;
      height: 700px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .bubbleChart svg{
      background: #000000;
    }
```

```html
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/d3-transform/src/d3-transform.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/cafej/src/extarray.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/cafej/src/misc.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/cafej/src/micro-observer.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/microplugin/src/microplugin.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/bubble-chart/src/bubble-chart.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/bubble-chart/src/plugins/central-click/central-click.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phuonghuynh.github.io/js/bower_components/bubble-chart/src/plugins/lines/lines.js"></script>

<div id="newBubbleChart"></div>
```

Here, you'll see that there is no `click` on the center element, and that it is being appended to a `div` with an id of `newBubbleChart`, rather than the previous one which had a class of `bubbleChart`.

Two changes were required for this:

1. Comment out the code for the `plugin` that handled the center clicking:

   ```
   plugins: [
   /*
     {
       name: "central-click",
       options: {
         text: "(See more detail)",
         style: {
           "font-size": "12px",
           "font-style": "italic",
           "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
           //"font-weight": "700",
           "text-anchor": "middle",
           "fill": "white"
         },
         attr: {dy: "65px"},
         centralClick: function() {
           alert("Here is more details!!");
         }
       }
     },
   */
     {
       name: "lines",
       options: {
         format: [
           {// Line #0
             textField: "count",
             classed: {count: true},
             style: {
               "font-size": "28px",
               "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
               "text-anchor": "middle",
                   fill: "white"
             },
             attr: {
               dy: "0px",
               x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                   y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
             }
           },
           {// Line #1
             textField: "text",
             classed: {text: true},
                 style: {
               "font-size": "14px",
               "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
               "text-anchor": "middle",
               fill: "white"
             },
             attr: {
               dy: "20px",
               x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
               y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
             }
           }
         ],
         centralFormat: [
           {// Line #0
             style: {"font-size": "50px"},
             attr: {}
           },
           {// Line #1
             style: {"font-size": "30px"},
             attr: {dy: "40px"}
           }
         ]
       }
     }]
   ```
2. Added a new option to the configuration of the bubble chart object:

   ```
   container: "#newBubbleChart",
   ```

   This provides the selection parameter to select the DOM element to add the bubble chart to.
   The code you copy and pasted even includes a commented out `container` parameter that could have provided you a clue with where to start looking.

These are documented on the link at the start of the answer.